# How to add a class to denote if fallback fonts are used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

Working with a client whose company has a group policy to disallow font downloads, so I need to go through and create fallback fonts for pretty much everything. Since the current fonts render quite differently from the system fonts we'll need to use, I need to adjust font size and possibly other attributes if the fallback font is used. I'm wondering how one would make a script that does something like:

If remote fonts can not be loaded, apply class "fallback" to body.

Or if there is a better way to handle such an issue.

Comment: Edited to make more narrow, though I disagree that it was too broad in the first place (particularly since Pomax has demonstrated one potential solution in a fairly short post already).

Answer (score 1):

Define two stylesheets: one with rules that specifically define your fonts in terms of webfonts, and a second that defines your text styling in terms of "web safe" fonts.

Then you can use JavaScript to try to load a webfont, see if it loaded, if not, remove the stylesheet node from the document stylesheet list that relies on webfonts, and then add a new `<link>` to the `<head>` for the "web safe" stylesheet instead.

This'll cenrtainly be potentially janky due to load timeouts (how long do you wait before you decide a webfont didn't load and swap in "web safe" styling?), but to be fair: to be expected when your group policies are set up to literally not support the modern web.

Webfonts are part and parcel of the modern web, disallowing them is a bit like setting a group policy that forbids JS execution: "why are you on the web to begin with, you clearly don't want to be there".

Comment: I completely agree with you on the absurdness of the group policy - unfortunately my arguments against the policy haven't netted a change.

Comment: might be worth checking if loading a font via `data-uri` is considered "downloading fonts" or not. If not, you can sidestep the restriction that way (get the font from a domain that lets you convert the bytecode to base64 using an XHR, then form a data-uri and load it "inline" in the CSS)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this technique. Could you maybe add an answer with a bit of detail on it?

Comment: I'll point you to https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ instead. That idea is pretty straight-forward: convert the binary file to a base64 string (many tools can do this, including the browser itself) and then where you would normally say `href="link.to.my/file"` or `url(link.tomy/file)`, you just drop the whole thing in as `href="data:application/font-woff;base64, ......"` or `url(data:application/font-woff;base64, ......)`. It makes your CSS files huge of course, so you want to load them async, or at the end of the `<body>`